# R function (Loop?) to make a new graph for each column in a dataset

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write the code to use my dataset and make a new graph for each column of a dataset, rather than have to write out a new value for y each time in the code.

I have a dataset where each row is a person, each column is a measurement in the blood (ie, insulin, glucose, etc). I have a few extra columns with descriptive categories that I"m using for my groups (ie lean, obese).  I'd like to make a graph for each of those column measurements (ie, one graph for insulin, another for glucose, etc). I have 90 different variables to cycle through.

I've figured out how to a boxplot for each of these, but can't figure out how to have the code "loop"? so that I don't have to re-write the code for each variable.

### Using the mtcars dataset as an example, I have it making a graph where the y is disp, and then another graph where y = hp, and then y = drat.

```
data("mtcars")

#boxplot with individual points - first y variable
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point()

#boxplot with individual points - 2nd y variable
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = hp)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point()

#boxplot with individual points - 3rd y variable
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = drat)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point()
```

How do I set this up so my code will automatically cycle through all of the variables in the dataset (I have 90 of them)?

Comment: What are you going to do with the 90 plots in the end? Asking because you might want to take a look at `facet_wrap` or (even better) `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` after you reshaped your data from wide to long.

Comment: Ok - will take a look.  At this point I just want to do a quick visualization of the data.  Happy to try either of those if it'll do the same thing, but put them in a nicer format.  Can you help direct me on how to use that function?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic solution, where you would populate `vector_of_yvals` with your 90 variables to loop through:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_func <- function(yval){
  p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = yval)) +
    geom_boxplot()+
    geom_point()
  p
}


vector_of_yvals <- c("disp", "hp", "drat")

list_of_plots <- map(vector_of_yvals, plot_func)
```

You can populate `vector_of_yvals` with all of the variables in your dataframe by doing:

```
vector_of_yvals <- colnames(mtcars)
```

This will give you a vector:

```
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

If you don't want to include `cyl` in your vector, you can filter it out like so:

```
vector_of_yvals <- vector_of_yvals %>% .[. != "cyl"]
```

Comment: Do I have to type out each of those y values, or is there a way to have this done without typing each one?  ie  vector_of_yvals <- c("disp":"drat")

Comment: You can use this: `vector_of_yvals <- names(mtcars)[3:5]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different version using a for loop and the using `!!sym()` to evaluate the variable text string:

```
library(rlang)
variables<-c("disp", "hp", "drat")

for (var in variables) {
  # print(var)
   p<-ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = !!sym(var), group=cyl)) +
      geom_boxplot()+
      geom_point()
   print(p)
}
```

Comment: This is working great!  I'm now trying to use the suggestion of ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate so my graphs are not 1 per page.  I think the code needs to be added before the print command, but don't know what the first "facets" should be  ' `facet_wrap_paginate((facets, nrow = 9, ncol = 10,
  scales = "free", shrink = TRUE, labeller = "label_value",
  as.table = TRUE, switch = NULL, drop = TRUE, dir = "h",
  strip.position = "top", page = 1)`

Comment: To use `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` you will have to reshape your data from the wide form to a long format.  `tidyr::pivot_longer()` is the function to perform that transformation.